# React Native FlatList renderItem does not return anything despite receiving correct data

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Here is the `renderItem` function:

```jsx
  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    getPost(item.id)
      .then((postContent) => {
        if (postContent.postType === 0) {
          console.log(postContent);
          console.log('Rendering type text post');
          return <TextPost item={postContent} index={index} />;
        } else if (postContent.postType === 1) {
          console.log(postContent);
          console.log('Rendering type image post');
          return <ImagePost item={postContent} index={index} />;
        } else {
          console.log(postContent);
          console.log('Rendering type link post');
          return <LinkPost item={postContent} index={index} />;
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

`renderItem` works on an array of post ids that exist in my database. For each id, the FlatList should call my `getPost` method with `item.id` as a parameter, and then fetch the post data from my database with the corresponding post id. This works, as my `console.log` statements print out the correct data for the given array of post ids. However, the return statements do not return any components, and the `FlatList` renders blank.
Here is the FlatList in case that helps:

```jsx
<FlatList data={data} renderItem={renderItem} style={styles.list} />
```

Comment: I guess it’s because async code. Use state variables for storing postContent

Comment: Why not store the fetched data inside `state` and then use it inside `renderItem` ?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze attempting this now, but it is doing an infinite render. I am trying to debug it right now.

Comment: @usafder attempting this now, but it is doing an infinite render. I am trying to debug it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Render, you can't use an async function, because render can't wait for your function to be executed. Rather do this stuff in componentDidMount create your array and put it in the state and use the state in flatlist.